# german date format for the datepicker of ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, datepicker, formatting, ng-bootstrap

I need your help using NgbDateParserFormatter for the datepicker of ng-bootstrap. I need the german format dd.MM.yyyy (for example 31.03.2017).

I have got a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hmabO1xbPkENLiZZHUJn?p=preview), but it does not work correctly:

- selecting some dates work (selecting for example 17.03.2017 leads to 17.03.2017)
- selecting some dates do not work (selecting 02.09.1937 gets to 01.09.1937)
- typing a date swaps day and month (01.03.2017 gets to 03.01.2017 and 14.03.2017 gets to an empty input due to there is no 03.14.2017)

Here is the code:

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class CustomNgbDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {
    datePipe = new DatePipe('de-AT');
    constructor(
        private dateFormatString: string) {
        super();
    }
    format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
        if (date === null) {
            return '';
        }
        try {
            return this.datePipe.transform(new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day), this.dateFormatString);
        } catch (e) {
            return '';
        }
    }
    parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
        let returnVal: NgbDateStruct;
        if (!value) {
            returnVal = null;
        } else {
            try {
                let dateParts = this.datePipe.transform(value, 'M-d-y').split('-');
                returnVal = { year: parseInt(dateParts[2]), month: parseInt(dateParts[0]), day: parseInt(dateParts[1]) };
            } catch (e) {
                returnVal = null;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Could you help me, please?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are making your life harder for yourself by using JS `Date` objects and the `DatePipe`. Those are problematic for the following reasons:

- `Date` JS objects carry time and time-zone information so without being careful you can easily get into time-zone conversion related issues - this is precisely why ng-bootstrap is using dedicated data structures
- `DataPipe` uses Intl API under the hood and it is quite buggy, unfortunately.

The good news is that you can easily implement desired functionality by following the ISO parser / formatter as seen here: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/088363551b5d5ecd602a82aedfc97d43a75a080f/src/datepicker/ngb-date-parser-formatter.ts#L25-L45

If I'm reading your intention correctly, your code could look like follows:

```
export class CustomNgbDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {

    format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
      return date ? `${padNumber(date.month)}.${padNumber(date.day)}.${date.year}` : '';
    }

    parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
        if (value) {
      const dateParts = value.trim().split('.');
      if (dateParts.length === 1 && isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
        return {year: null, month: toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: null};
      } else if (dateParts.length === 2 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
        return {year: null, month: toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: toInteger(dateParts[1])};
      } else if (dateParts.length === 3 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1]) && isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
        return {year: toInteger(dateParts[2]), month: toInteger(dateParts[0]), day: toInteger(dateParts[1])};
      }
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Here is a plunker showing this in action: https://plnkr.co/edit/JdX0eHcl7QddOWxM9aT0?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but selecting a date by cursor results to a date where day and month are swapped. Typing a date lets the date to be correct.

Comment: @kanlo I thought that you are targeting the month-day-year format and this is what is implemented in the linked plunker, no? In any case if you aiming for a different format it should be trivial to adapt the code I've linked.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly pkozlowski.opensource answer but with swapped month/day since that's the common format in Germany.

```
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

function padNumber(value: number) {
    if (isNumber(value)) {
        return `0${value}`.slice(-2);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}

function toInteger(value: any): number {
    return parseInt(`${value}`, 10);
}

function isNumber(value: any): boolean {
    return !isNaN(toInteger(value));
}

export class CustomNgbDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {

    format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
        return date ? `${padNumber(date.day)}.${padNumber(date.month)}.${date.year}` : '';
    }

    parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
        if (value) {
            const dateParts = value.trim().split('.');
            if (dateParts.length === 1 && isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
                return { year: null, day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: null };
            } else if (dateParts.length === 2 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1])) {
                return { year: null, day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: toInteger(dateParts[1]) };
            } else if (dateParts.length === 3 && isNumber(dateParts[0]) && isNumber(dateParts[1]) && isNumber(dateParts[2])) {
                return { year: toInteger(dateParts[2]), day: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: toInteger(dateParts[1]) };
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution I hope it will help you.
To make it work you have to make an entry in **app.module.ts** like this:

```
providers: [...,
{ provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: NgbDateFRParserFormatter }]
```

> You select a date from datepicker or enter the date manually, It will automatical converts its format to dd.MM.yyyy.

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDateStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@Injectable()
export class NgbDateFRParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {

parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct {
if (value) {
  const dateParts = value.trim().split('/');
  if (dateParts.length === 1 && isNumber(dateParts[0])) {
    return { year: toInteger(dateParts[0]), month: null, day: null };
  } else if (
    dateParts.length === 2 &&
    isNumber(dateParts[0]) &&
    isNumber(dateParts[1])
  ) {
    return {
      year: toInteger(dateParts[1]),
      month: toInteger(dateParts[0]),
      day: null
    };
  } else if (
    dateParts.length === 3 &&
    isNumber(dateParts[0]) &&
    isNumber(dateParts[1]) &&
    isNumber(dateParts[2])
  ) {
    return {
      year: toInteger(dateParts[2]),
      month: toInteger(dateParts[1]),
      day: toInteger(dateParts[0])
    };
  }
}
 return null;
}


format(date: NgbDateStruct): string {
let stringDate = '';
const language = this.authService.getUser().language;

  if (date) {
    stringDate += isNumber(date.day) ? padNumber(date.day) + '.' : '';
    stringDate += isNumber(date.month) ? padNumber(date.month) + '.' : '';
    stringDate += date.year;
  }
   return stringDate;
  }
 }

 function padNumber(value: number) {
  if (isNumber(value)) {
  return `0${value}`.slice(-2);
 } else {
  return '';
 }
}

 function isNumber(value: any): boolean {
   return !isNaN(toInteger(value));
}

   function toInteger(value: any): number {
   return parseInt(`${value}`, 10);
  }
```